# Bug with Block & Lookup: Scope Variable Leak

Tags: bugs, scoping, associations

After debugging a large chunk of code, I could identify this [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example).

```
ClearAll@test
test[var_String]:= Block[{association},
    association = <|"x"-> <|"key01"-> "ok"|>|>[var];
    Lookup[association,"key01",{}]
]
```

If I evaluate:

```
test["x"]
test["y"]
test["x"]
```

I get an error evaluating the last `test["x"]`. What is very strange, I expected to find an error just in the evaluation of `test["y"]`.

The same error does not occur if we change from `Block` to `Module`. In the `Block` case, we have some sort of unexpected scope leak. Is this a bug?

Tested in Mathematica version 11.3
[Cross post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1241974) in Mathematica Community

Still bugged in version 12.1

Comment: `Lookup` has the attribute `HoldAllComplete`, which means it sees the symbol `association`, not its value.  I don't think the bug is in `Block`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I did a smaller toy code. But I don't understand why the memory. Why I get error when evaluation test["x"] by the second time.

Comment: I don't know enough (or any) of the internals of `Associations`.  It looks like `Lookup` is remembering something perhaps.  `Lookup` being the newer thing, I suspect it over `Block`; but I don't know for sure.  Hopefully someone who knows more can explain. -- I guess it's clear it's the combination of both, since using a global `association` doesn't suffer the same problem.

Comment: I would say that there is a bug in an internal caching mechanism in the implementation of `Lookup`.  I note that if we evaluate `Update[Lookup]` to flush its hidden caches, then `test["x"]` starts working again.

Comment: This doesn't happen for `Module` because running a second time creates a new instantiation of `association`. `In[1]:= Table[Module[{x}, x], 2]

Out[1]= {x$5672, x$5673}`.

Answer (score 19):

Looks like a bug to me as well. Just as Michael I would suspect that the problem is more with `Lookup` than `Block` or `Association`s in general. Here is a code example which seems to confirm that it is `Lookup` which does some caching and obviously doesn't take into account that the `Block`ed variables value has changed:

```
ClearAll@test
test[var_String] := Block[{association},
   association = <|"x" -> <|"key01" -> "ok"|>|>[var];
   Print[association@"key01"];
   Lookup[association, "key01", {}]
]
```

Doing your tests with the above shows that directly access will give the correct result, while only the call to `Lookup` does not do what is to be expected. It also looks like this only happens when the shown error occurs, it does not happen if no error occurs. I would suggest you file a report to WRI.